# findByIdAndUpdate do not update document

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a field to the document with findByIdAndUpdate. The field I am trying to update is defined in the Bar Model. And I can also assure that `req.body.bookId` has a valid id.

Here's how my request looks,

```
app.patch("/foo", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await validateId(req.body.bookId);

        let doc = await Bar.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.body.bookId,
            { DateT: Date.now() },
            { new: true }
        );

        res.send(doc);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Bar schema,

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const barSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    bookId: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
    },
    DateT: {
        type: Date,
        default: null,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Bar", barSchema);
```

Comment: I founded your problem, you assign a id to bookId but you didn't assign its to `_id ` key and so you can not use `findByIdAndUpdatene`because different id generate for _id

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi, yes you are right. Using `updateOne` and passing `bookId` to query works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `updateOne`, when you use `async` don't use `.then()` use `try/catch`

test it:

```
app.patch("/foo", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let doc = await Bar.updateOne(
      { bookId : req.body.bookId },
      { DateT: Date.now() },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.send(doc);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. And about using `$set`, that was the not the cause, you might call it ['useless' right there for this use case](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate). Also, I have tried with try catch too, not working.

Comment: @MohammadYasarAhmadi, I have updated my code snippet as well, and this doesn't work.

Comment: if req.body.id is a mongoose.Types.objectId, maybe something wrong in your Schema

Comment: req.body.id is a string and so it is defined in schema.

Comment: id no need to defined in Schema, it's generate automatically

Comment: can you added your Schema to the question

Comment: I mean `bookId` is defined as string, not `id`. Sure, I am adding the schema.

Comment: when you use `findByIdAndUpdate` it searches on `_id` key not `bookId`

Comment: yes, and I pass `bookId` to be searched on `id`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227220/discussion-between-hasan-and-mohammad-yaser-ahmadi).

Comment: I updated my answer, can you check it again?

Comment: It shouldn't be `{bookId = req.body.bookId}`, it should be `{bookId : req.body.bookId}`. I have made an edit fixing this @MohammadYaserAhmadi

Answer (score 0):

```
app.patch("/foo", async (req, res) => {
    await Bar.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.body.bookId,
        { DateT: Date.now()},
        (err, docs) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.send(docs);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Just a change of variable name not going to make it work mate, not in this case. It would work if the custom variable override any reserved variable which is not happening here.